# Frame by frame forward and backward

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set properties on a video where arrowLeft keypress is -1 frame and arrowright keypress is +1 frame, but I not able to prevent default behavior.

I've tried using `e.preventDefautl() e.stopPropagation` and return false.

```
<video id="video_1" class="video" controls class="video" width="800" height="600" mediagroup="videoMG1" autobuffer preload >
    <source src="{{movie["url"]}}"  />
</video>
```

```
var video = document.getElementById("video_1");

video.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
  return false;
});
video.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
  return false;
});
var video2 = VideoFrame({
    id: 'video_1',
    frameRate: 25.00,
    callback: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});

video.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation() 
  debugger;
  if( e.KeyCode == 39 ){
    console.log("backward")
    video.seekBackward(1)
  }else if( e.KeyCode == 37) {
    console.log("forwrd")
    video.seekForward(1)
  }
  return false;
});
```

When I enter the debugger, the video has already process the keypressed and moved forward 7 seconds instead of a frame as I would like to.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: https://codepen.io/blackjacques/pen/bgamaj
for video controls exemple if someone need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the standard controls displayed by the browser itself.

The only way to get around this is deactivating it completely using:

```
video.controls=false;
```

Furthermore you're calling the **seekBackward()** and **seekForward()** methods on the wrong object. I assume you're using the [VideoFrame](https://github.com/allensarkisyan/VideoFrame) library, do you?

At the moment you're doing it like this

```
video.seekBackward(1);
```

This is the html5 video element itself - you need to use the VideoFrame object, **video2** in your case.

```
video2.seekBackward(1);
```

Here's the full code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="VideoFrame.min.js"></script>
    <video id="video_1" class="video" controls class="video" width="800" height="600" mediagroup="videoMG1" autobuffer preload>
            <source src="myVideo.mp4"  />
        </video>
    <div id="videoControls">
      <button type="button" id="playPause">&#9205;</button>
      <button type="button" id="mute">&#128266;</button>
      <input type="range" id="volumeBar" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
    </div>
    <script>
      var video = document.getElementById("video_1");
      var video2 = VideoFrame({
        id: 'video_1',
        frameRate: 25.00,
        callback: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
      video.controls = false;
      video.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        console.log("asd", e.keyCode)
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
          console.log("backward")
          video2.seekBackward(1)
        } else if (e.KeyCode == 37) {
          console.log("forwrd")
          video2.seekForward(1)
        }
        return false;
      });

      document.getElementById("playPause").addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (video.paused == true) {
          video.play();
          this.innerHTML = "&#9208;";
        } else {
          video.pause();
          this.innerHTML = "&#9205;";
        }
      });

      document.getElementById("mute").addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (video.muted == false) {
          video.muted = true;
          this.innerHTML = "&#128263;";
        } else {
          video.muted = false;
          this.innerHTML = "&#128266;";
        }
      });

      document.getElementById("volumeBar").addEventListener("input", function() {
        video.volume = volumeBar.value;
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: indeed that resolve the issue of stopping default behavior, but i'll need to code all default behavior including the overlay for play pause timer etc ? or is there something i can use to replace it

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid you have to make all of the controls yourself.

Comment: I've updated the example in my answer above to include some simple controls.